# Mono error when load testing

Tags: mono

During load testing (using Load UI) of a new .Net web api using Mono hosted on a medium sized Amazon server I'm receiving the following results (in chronological order over the course of about ten minutes)

5 connections per second for 60 seconds
No errors

50 connections per second for 60 seconds
No errors

100 connections per second for 60 seconds
Received 3 errors, appearing later during the run
2014-02-07 00:12:10Z    Error   HttpResponseExtensions  Error occured while Processing Request: [IOException] Write failure     Write failure|The socket has been shut down
2014-02-07 00:12:10Z    Info    HttpResponseExtensions  Failed to write error to response: {0}  Cannot be changed after headers are sent.

5 connections per second for 60 seconds
No errors

100 connections per second for 30 seconds
No errors

100 connections per second for 60 seconds
Received 1 error same as above, appearing later during the run

100 connections per second for 45 seconds
No errors

Doing some research on this, this error seems to be a standard one received when a client closed the connection. As this is only occurring during the heavier load tests, I am wondering if it is just getting to the upper limits of what the server instance can support? If not any suggestions on hunting down the source of the errors?

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: Mono version is 3.0.1 loaded on a Centos distribution